# Enforcing Formatting Standards Using VSCode settings.json as Part of a Jar

Tags: maven, visual-studio-code, jar, karate

Because Karate open source implements a few different styles into the DSL(BDD, JS, Java), there isn't really a good tool like ESLint out there to support it.  Was thinking to package the `settings.json` file to enforce some minimum standardization such as tabs, but maybe this is not a good solution?

Comment: Looks like `editorConfig` may be a better way to go, not sure if it can be read from a package though..